# UIView.transition does not move UIView content on first side

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, uiview

I am using UIView.transition(with: duration: options: animations:) function to flip card. When I am animating frame property while transition is still in work, the first UIView state is not moving, its position is stack to parent view, but the second state on the other side of card is moving and animating perfectly.
How to fix that? Thank you.

Explaining the code: UIView.animate being called twice. First time being executed **animations** closure and then **completion** closure. It's ok here. Next, when I press button (see video) completion body will NOT be executed anymore because of **if** statement, but the trouble is when **completion** closure from the first time still animating flipping transition, **animations** closure being executing the second time and moving the card to the new position. All content on the first card side is not moving with second animation, though second side works perfect.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2,
               delay: delay,
               options: [],
               animations: { [unowned self] in
                        self.frame = CGRect(origin: newFrame.origin, size: newFrame.size)
               },
               completion: { [unowned self] (position) in
                   if self.destination != self.state {
                        UIView.transition(with: self,
                                          duration: 8,
                                          options: [.transitionFlipFromLeft, UIViewAnimationOptions.layoutSubviews],
                                          animations: {[unowned self] in
                                              self.state = self.destination
                                              self.setNeedsDisplay()
                        },
                                          completion: { (position) in

                   })
               }
})
```

Here is the video https://youtu.be/lRYT_6xWbWA

On screenshot cards are moving up and scaling a bit with property animation.

[image]

Comment: Can you share some of your code?  How are the two sides of the cards related? Are they subviews of another view?  Are you using Auto Layout at all? Which view's frame are you animating?  Please share your animation code.

Comment: I've added code and explained in detail what happens.